# CollectionView didDeselectItemAt not getting called for Single selection in CollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Following is my code for CollectionView

```
    categoryCollectionView.delegate = self
    categoryCollectionView.dataSource = self
    categoryCollectionView.allowsSelection = true
    categoryCollectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = false
```

Following is UICollectionViewCell code

```
class AppPageCategoryViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
var catgory : String?

@IBOutlet weak var titleLbl: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var closeImageView: UIImageView!



@IBOutlet weak var stackContainer: UIView!
var facet : Facets?

func setUI() {
    titleLbl.text = facet?.name ?? ""
    let isSelected = facet?.isSelected ?? false
    stackContainer.layer.borderColor =  UIColor.black.cgColor
    stackContainer.backgroundColor = isSelected ? UIColor.black : UIColor.white
    titleLbl.textColor = isSelected ? UIColor.white : UIColor.black
    closeImageView.image = closeImageView.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    closeImageView.tintColor = UIColor.hexStringToUIColor(hex: AppStrings.whiteColor)
    stackContainer.layer.cornerRadius =  16
    stackContainer.layer.borderWidth = 1
    closeImageView.isHidden = !isSelected

  }
}
```

Following is select deselct method

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    print("deselect----------deselect")

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

     print("select----------select")

}
```

Now **didDeselectItemAt** is not getting called if I select one and item and select another item or if I select same item **didDeselectItemAt** not getting called at all it is just calling **didSelectItemAt** method why ? how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This delegate method isn’t triggered because you set the Boolean “allowsMultipleSelection” to false. It needs to be true to allow the deselection of the item.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614938-allowsmultipleselection

EDIT:

I believe what you need to do here is to use the delegate method "shouldSelectItemAt" of the collectionView to check wether or not the cell being tapped on is already selected or not. If true, then you can deselect it, if false, do nothing.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    if let currentIndexPathSelected = cellSelectedIndexPath, currentIndexPathSelected == indexPath {
        collectionView.deselectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        collectionView.delegate?.collectionView?(collectionView, didDeselectItemAt: indexPath)
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

cellSelectedIndexPath is a private var to hold the current selected indexPath.

Calling the delegate will trigger the didDeselectItemAt method.

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: You maybe want to try to use the delegate method "collectionView(_:shouldSelectItemAt:)" then, and return false if one cell is already selected, return true otherwise. If the cell tapped is the one selected you can return true as well, this will deselect it.